# unique redirect both login and register in woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, redirect

I'm looking to utilize the [woocommerce_my_account] shortcode to create the login and register forms on a unique page.

I'd like to make both parts of this form redirect to a different url.  This should not be global, only the form on this unique page.

In functions.php I've added

```
function free_redirect( $redirect ){
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/unique-page/") !== false){
    $redirect = '/new_url/';
    return $redirect;
  }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'free_redirect');

function redirect_register( $redirect ){
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/unique-page/") !== false){
    $redirect = '/new_url/';
    return $redirect;
  }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'redirect_register');
```

The two problems I'm encountering are:

1) Register still does not redirect just goes to the my-account page per normal behavior

2) It's affecting other login forms in that when they are submitted their redirect doesn't yield any html content on the next page(logs don't tell me anything about this but I suspect it's because the filter is causing some problems due to me not ending the functions correctly).

P.S. I've read about adding a hidden input field to append a query string and then use that instead of the request_uri, but I'd like to keep this simple and clean.

Please let me know what I'm missing or if there are any better options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for login redirect this piece of code will do your job.

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect ) {
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/unique-page/' ){
        $redirect = '/new_url/';
        return $redirect;
    }
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect');
```

It actually checks the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to your `/unique-page/`. If matches it executes the code otherwise it will redirect to default `$redirect`.

Same things happens to registration redirects also-

```
function redirect_register( $redirect ){
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/unique-page/' ){
        $redirect = '/new_url/';
        return $redirect;
    }
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'redirect_register');
```

And for your third question-

> P.S. I've read about adding a hidden input field to append a query
>   string and then use that instead of the request_uri, but I'd like to
>   keep this simple and clean.

Yes, there is a way. You can use-

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form', 'add_redirect_field' );
function add_redirect_field() {
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/unique-page/' ){
        echo '<p><input type="hidden" name="redirect-token" value="your-custom-token-for-redirect" /></p>';     
    }
}
```

Then use conditional logic to redirect to your desired page.

Comment: For the login portion...I was forgetting the return to default redirect...so that problem is fixed.  But I do still need to figure out the register redirect as the unique URL changes to /my-account/ when the register script is ran thus returning false for the register if statement when checking for the unique-page.

Comment: Have you tried those snippets ? After trying the registration part snippet the registration redirect still doesn't work ? @user3549735

Comment: Sure did...and the problem as I see it for the registration page is the URL that the php script is checking changes to my-account as opposed to checking the REFERER, which I've been informed is bad practice because it is not always provided.

Comment: Can you please tell me the page  URL on which you've the registration page you created by the `[woocommerce_my_account]` ?

Comment: mydomain.com/unique-url/ is the page containing the form...on register it redirects to mydomain.com/my-account/?new_register=...

Comment: If you could elaborate on the conditional logic mentioned in the input hidden field, I'd appreciate it.  I've got the hidden field loading and I think something to the effect of if(isset($_REQUEST["redirect-token"])) hooked into either wp or woocommerce_registration_redirect might work, but so far my tests are not going great